# Add an "All" option with a value to SelectList in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is in my view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("id", ((SelectList)ViewBag.SelectList), "All")
```

Which creates this in markup:

```
<select id="id" name="id">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

But what I really want is this (with the value set):

```
<select id="id" name="id">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way for me to do this in the view by appending my first line of code? I know I could add this to the Dictionary (when it is a regular Dictionary, before I have converted it to a SelectList). I also know I could convert the blank value to this value in the receiving controller. Other than this, I am open to other options.

Comment: "I could add this to the Dictionary (when it is a regular Dictionary, before I have converted it to a SelectList)." This is the approach I would take. Much cleaner than doing anything in the view to add/configure the item. Preferably a view should contain as little logic as possible.

Comment: Thanks. I actually came up with an alternative myself, but am wondering still if this way is possible.

Comment: You could use a `@for(int idx = 0;idx < ((SelectList)ViewBag.SelectList).Length;idx++)` (this is rough code, may not work first time) loop, manually iterating through each item and outputting `<option....>` elements yourself. You could check the value of `idx` and if it's o then add your `All` item.

Comment: How about writing a custom HTML helper extension method